# PS4 and Gran Turismo Sport menu sound effects

Tags: sound-design, game, interface

I try to figure out how to do some ambient interface sound effects like in the ps4 menu and in gran turismo.

I like especially the 3 sounds after second 14 of this video.

Is there any tutorial, or somebody knows how to recreate these? When i try to make these sounds with synthesizers i get close to them but something is missing and i can't figure out what it is. I am looking for some best practices, because often when i do interface sounds it's just turning knobs randomly until it sounds like i want, i never know any good starting point.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert but I have already created sounds like that using only NI's Massive, and I'm quite sure you can do the same with many synths.

I would recommend trying to understand the nature of each sound effect: type of attack and delay, interval or chord (if so, which one?), the effects used (reverb? delay?), the number of separate layers, etc.

Good luck!